# Sorting according to [Int] operands in Swift

Tags: swift

I'm developing a poker game.

I have a zipped sequence Zip2Sequence<[String], [(Int, [Int])]> where the string is the hand, followed by a ranking of the hand according to the cards held (Straight = 8, four of a kind = 4) followed by an array of Integer to differentiate between two hands given the same rank.

I understand that I can compare two [Int] operands: in a playground session I try

```
print ([1,5] > [1,4]) //true
print ([1,4] > [1,5]) //false
```

[image]

However in my code I want to differentiate my hands with the same highest rank, and use the following function

```
func differentiateHighestRanks (_ zippled: Zip2Sequence<[String], [(Int, [Int])]>  ) -> String  {
    let highestrank = zippled.enumerated().max{ $0.element.1.1 < $1.element.1.1 }
    return highestrank
}
```

Returning the error Binary operator < cannot be applied to two [Int] operands.

Well, Swift, I disagree. Usually in these cases, though, it turns out I'm wrong. So why am I wrong, and how can I return the largest [Int]?

Comment: If anything, it's wrong that the playground code works like that. If you assign them to variables which automatic typing, it no longer works and gives the same error. I was trying to see if the inferred type was different than [Int]. Why don't you just properly implement the comparison of [Int] the way you'd like it to behave?

Comment: Well, yes, that is a solution. But without understanding why I perceive an inconsistency I'm potentially reinventing the wheel or allowing a misunderstanding to manifest.

Comment: The first example does not work in an Xcode 8.3.3 playground. I get: "Binary operator '>' cannot be applied to two '[Int]’ operands”. What version of Xcode are you using?

Comment: 8.3.3 (8E3004b) - Also just started a fresh session with just those two lines - What is going on?

Comment: Are you pulling in any other Frameworks? You’re on the same version that I am and I don’t see the same behavior. Try that code in a brand-new playground with nothing else.

Comment: Just restarted Xcode - just have UIKit??

Comment: Added an image to the post - I've no clue

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147415/discussion-between-colgraff-and-stevenpcurtis).

Comment: Apparently the [Int] comparison behavior comes from importing Foundation. I would not rely on it, a custom method would be more controllable and predictable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summarizing from the comments:

This works only when you have `Foundation` imported:

```
print ([1,5] > [1,4]) //true
print ([1,4] > [1,5]) //false
```

It appears that Swift is inferring the types of `[1,5]` and `[1,4]` to be `IndexPath`.  Why would it do that?  Because it is possible to compare `IndexPath` with `>` *and* `IndexPath` can be initialized with an array literal like so:

```
let a: IndexPath = [1, 5]
```

You can convert `[Int]` to `IndexPath` like so:

```
IndexPath(indexes: myArrayOfInt)
```

Applying that to your `differentiateHighestRanks` function, and altering the return value to extract the `String` results in this:

```
func differentiateHighestRanks (_ zippled: Zip2Sequence<[String], [(Int, [Int])]>  ) -> String  {
    let highestrank = zippled.enumerated().max{ IndexPath(indexes: $0.element.1.1) < IndexPath(indexes: $1.element.1.1) }
    return highestrank!.1.0
}
```

If you were to use `IndexPath` in this way, you might want to use `map` to convert the `[Int]` to `IndexPath` once instead of repeatedly converting it during the comparison.

Also, if you are comparing the values of hands, I believe you'd want to sort the `[Int]` in descending order so that *highest card wins*.